# sketching the Takagi function

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I have an exercise on the Takagi function and I don't understand the construction. Here's how it goes.

Let $f(x)= \mid x \mid$ for $-\frac{1}{2} \leq x \leq \frac{1}{2}$. We then extend $f$ on all $\mathbb{R}$ by making it 1-periodic, that means we require that $f(x+1)=f(x), \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Now, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we define

$$ f_n(x)=\frac{f(4^nx)}{4^n}. $$

We call the limit-function

\begin{align*}
  T \colon \mathbb{R} &\to \mathbb{R}\\
  x &\mapsto \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f_n(x)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f(4^nx)}{4^n} .
\end{align*}

The Takagi function.

I don't understand how to sketch the sum. I mean if $f(x)=\mid x \mid$, then why is the following false ?

$$ f_n(x)= \frac{f(4^n x)}{4^n}= \frac{\mid 4^n x \mid}{4^n}=\mid x \mid. $$

Thank you for your kind help

Comment: But $f(x)$ is not $|x|$.

Comment: Could you please be more precise ? I wanted to sketch it on the interval $[-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}]$ but I only get $\mid x \mid$, am I missing something ?

Comment: The definition of $f$ tells you that $f(x)=|x|$ for $x$ between $-\frac12$ and $+\frac12$. In your calculation of $f_n(x)$, you used that $f(4^nx)=|4^nx|$, which is valid for $4^nx$ between $-\frac12$ and $+\frac12$. So this calculation is correct for $-\frac1{4^n2}\leq x\leq\frac1{4^n2}$. But you need $f_n(x)$ for $-\frac12\leq x\leq\frac12$, a much bigger range of $x$ values. So more calculation is needed.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your conclusion is correct, however, you neglected to consider the interval over which it is correct.

$$ f_n(x)= \frac{f(4^n x)}{4^n}= \frac{\mid 4^n x \mid}{4^n}=\mid x \mid\text{ for }-\frac{1}{2}\le4^nx\le\frac{1}{2} $$

So it reduces to $\mid x\mid$ only on the interval $-\dfrac{1}{2^{2n+1}}\le x\le\dfrac{1}{2^{2n+1}}$.

For comparison, here is the graph of $f_1(x)$ in black superimposed over the graph of $f(x)$ in red.

[image: graphs]

The following is the graph of $T_4(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^4\frac{f_n(x)}{4^n}$ using the closed form
$$ f(x)=\left|\, x-\left\lfloor x+\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor \,\right| $$

[image: Takagi Graph n=4]

Comment: Thank you very much for the very detailed answer. May I ask you how did you come up with the formula for $f(x)$ ? Also, what did you use to make you graphs ?

Comment: I have been using the floor and absolute value functions to produce saw-toothed functions for many years.  The first one of this type I used was $|x-\lfloor x\rfloor-1/2|$. You can then experiment to find others. For example, shift this one to the left by $1/2$ by replacing each $x$ by $x+1/2$ and you get the one that I used in the answer.

Comment: thank you for your answer

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

In fact we have $$ f_n(x)=\frac{f(4^nx)}{4^n}={|4^nx\mod 1|\over 4^n} $$